# Using computer vision for linear feature detection

Tags: remote-sensing, aerial-photography, machine-learning

I am considering to use CV methods to detect linear features in very high resolution imagery (i've added an example below). These linear features are made by animals which transverse this section of reed vegetation.

I've seen many examples of CV being used to detect animals, objects, etc but not so much to actual map these type of features in the landscape. In classical remote sensing we would look at edge detection algorithms (e.g. sobel filters) or image segmentation but those algorithms always feel like they end up tailored to that specific case. Ideally, i could train a model in location X and have good results in location Y.

I'm still in the design phase. So, I would like to know, what algorithms you would recommend and if you can, what type of challenges you expect me to experience?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.